# POSTGRESQL - Is it better to keep a db connection open from the moment a port is exposed or to open and close a connection for each request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

Title says it all.

Is it better to open a connection to my db when the app is initialized or should I connect and release the client for each query?

How do I use a connection pool correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Opening and closing database connections repeatedly is a waste of time and CPU power. Therefpre, you should always use a connection pool.

When you use a connection pool, you don't open and xlose the connection, but take it from the pool and return it when you are done.